# How to avoid input size shrinking in a Space component? [antd]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

My input takes the whole width, which is excepted behavior.

`<Input placeholder='Filter' style={{ marginBottom: 50}}/>`

[image]

Now I need to add a button behind this input. I decided to use the Space component, but then the input shrank. How can I have an input filling the whole space in a Space component ?

```
<Space>
<Input placeholder='Filter'/>
<Button type='primary'>Filter</Button>
</Space>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off just using a `div`. My personal experience with AntD is that it's really hard to "customize" layouts/spacing using their components, even when attempting to style them with the `style` attribute.

```js
// Works
<div style={{ display: "flex", gap: "8px" }}>
<Input placeholder='Filter'/>
<Button type='primary'>Filter</Button>
</div>

// Doesn't work
<Space style={{ display: "flex" }}>
<Input placeholder='Filter' style={{ flex: "auto" }} />
<Button type='primary'>Filter</Button>
</Space>
```

Comment: I did use the antd grid system and it worked as well